# Sprite Animation in Pygame Zero

Tags: animation, python, pygame, spritesheet

How do I use a sprite sheet in pygame zero?
The height of the images are 32, width is 25

Comment: Have you looked up guides for using spritesheet animations in Pygame, and tried using them in Zero? Where did you encounter a specific obstacle or incompatibility when doing this?

Comment: @DMGregory All pygame sprite tutorials use py. or some variation of that, pygame zero is simple, no code is necesarry to make a window in pygame zero, it could be a 100% blank file, and it accepts it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've probably discovered, Pygame Zero doesn't have direct support for spritesheets. If you want to programmatically extract the desired sprites from the sheet at run time you'll need to use python code to do that. There's  [spritesheet code on the Pygame wiki](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/Spritesheet).

Alternatively, you can use some other app to extract the sprites to individuals files for Pygame Zero to use. A web search for "spritesheet extractor" brings up a number of online options. You could also use most any image editing capable software (Photoshop, Gimp, Krite, Paint.net, etc) to manually extract the desired sprites.